# Eclipse on AIX crashes in cairo lib during start

Tags: eclipse

We are trying to get Eclipse Mars or Neon to run under AIX 6.1.

When starting Eclipse with the command line

```
/opt/eclipse45/eclipse -vm /usr/java8/bin/java
```

or

```
/opt/eclipse46/eclipse -vm /usr/java8/bin/java
```

the splash screen is displayed followed by a window with title "Workspace Launcher" (for Mars) or "Eclipse Launcher" (for Neon). Then Eclipse crashes with the following error message being displayed on the console:

```
Assertion failed: ret, file cairo-xlib-surface.c, line 1180
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution to our problem: it's the '-depth' parameter in the startup command for our vnc server Xvnc. With the default value of 16 Eclipse crashes on startup, with any other of the possible values (8, 15 or 24) Eclipse starts successfully. So the following command line for vnc works:

```
vncserver :1 -depth 15 -geometry 1920x1080
```